# Networkx node and edge indices and attributes

Tags: python, networkx

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
source = 0
target = 1
G.add_node(source, name='Ham')
G.add_node(target, name='Eggs')
G.add_edge(source, target, meal='Breakfast')
nodes = G.nodes(data=True)

for src, tgt, attr in G.edges(data=True):
    # print type(node1)
    src_id, src_attr = nodes[src]
    tgt_id, tgt_attr = nodes[tgt]
    print(str(src) + ' - ' + str(tgt) + ' : ' + attr['meal']
          + ' : ' + src_attr['name'] + ' , ' + tgt_attr['name'])
```

The code above produces the desired, correct output:

```
0 - 1 : Breakfast : Ham , Eggs
```

but the code is wrong. You can see that the code is wrong by replacing 0/1 with, say, 5/7.

**Short Question**

How can we continue to obtain the output `Breakfast : Ham , Eggs` if instead of `source = 0` and `target = 1` we use `source = 5` and `target = 7`?

**Long Question**

I'm also seeking an answer to these questions for a better understanding of why your solution to the short question works.

- If we uncomment the commented out line, we see that the type is `int`, but what are `src, tgt` in the `for` loop? The nodes objects or the node indices?
- The expression `nodes = G.nodes(data=True)` is of type `list`. Does this mean that if we replace `5` and `7` with `5000000` and `7000000`, we would be building a list this long?

Comment: This output is the correct one. What makes you think it is wrong? What would you expect?

Comment: @ValentinLorentz My "it" was ambiguous. It refers to the code, not the output. Reworded.

Comment: Ok. What do you mean by “correct output” in the short question?

Comment: @ValentinLorentz I see. Reworded again. `nodes[src]['name']` and `nodes[tgt]['name']` fail after replacing 0/1 with 5/7. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a node's attributes via `G.node`:

```
for src, tgt, attr in G.edges(data=True):
    # print type(node1)
    src_attr = nodes[src]
    tgt_attr = nodes[tgt]
    print(str(src) + ' - ' + str(tgt) + ' : ' + attr['meal']
          + ' : ' + src_attr['name'] + ' , ' + tgt_attr['name'])
```

---

In the for loop, `src` and `tgt` are node names/identifiers. networkx has no concept of node object, it manipulates names/identifiers directly.

---

The list returned by `G.nodes(data=True)` has length equal to the number of nodes.
As node names/identifiers can be arbitrary types, it would not make sense to create a list of size `x` if `x` is a string.

Here is an example of strings are node names/identifiers:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
source = 'foo'
target = 'bar'
G.add_node(source, name='Ham')
G.add_node(target, name='Eggs')
G.add_edge(source, target, meal='Breakfast')

for src, tgt, attr in G.edges(data=True):
    # print type(node1)
    src_attr = G.node[src]
    tgt_attr = G.node[tgt]
    print(str(src) + ' - ' + str(tgt) + ' : ' + attr['meal']
          + ' : ' + src_attr['name'] + ' , ' + tgt_attr['name'])
```

It outputs this:

```
foo - bar : Breakfast : Ham , Eggs
```

Comment: may be worth mentioning that the nodes themselves must be hashable as networkx stores the network as a dictionary whose keys are the nodes and whose values contain data about the network structure.

Comment: Interesting. It's puzzling why `nodes = dict(G.nodes(data=True))` is not an established idiom (or is it?).

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I finally remembered the right way to do this: `G.node[x]`. Answer edited.

Comment: After your last edit I'm confused again. Shouldn't you say "You can access a node's attributes via G.node only if you use integer indices for node identifiers, starting from zero."?

Comment: @calaf `G`'s nodes can be anything hashable, and `G.node` is simply a dict whose keys are the nodes of `G` and whose values are the attributes of the nodes.  Try printing `G.node` to get an idea of what the underlying data structure looks like.